# php extra line breaks showing up

Tags: php, echo, line-breaks, isset

I'm a total newbie with php. I'm returning some variables for an address and am checking to see if an address2 exists. If it's null, I want it to skip and not put an extra line in the formatting. But, it seems to be breaking the line anyway. I've experimented with break tags all over the place and not, but can't find where it's coming in.

```
echo "$comp_name<br>$comp_add1";
if (isset($comp_add2)) {
    echo "<br>$comp_add2"; }
echo "<br>$comp_city, $comp_state $comp_zip<br><a href=\"http://$comp_url\" >$comp_url</a>";
```

Take a look at this page: http://projects.ekcetera.com/people.php ... click on ABC Company, then check A Simplified Life, you'll see the extra line break in A Simplified Life.

What am I missing?

Comment: you want empty() not isset()

Comment: looks like I had to use !empty(), thanks!

Comment: Just saying, you should as well take a look at proper HTML formatting...

Comment: @TheDeadLike and by that you mean....? If you're referring to the usage of <br> - I haven't done any HTML work yet, just trying to get the back-end work and data working...formatting to come - I most certainly won't be using <br> to style everything. Not much of a constructive comment with no background into what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in A Simplified Life your $comp_add2 is set , you must check is it null or not

```
echo "$comp_name<br>$comp_add1";
if (!empty($comp_add2)) {
    echo "<br>$comp_add2"; }
echo "<br>$comp_city, $comp_state $comp_zip<br><a href=\"http://$comp_url\" >$comp_url</a>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example page shows a fatal error, but I assume you have to use empty here, because the variable might be set, but only filled with an empty string.

So

```
if (isset($comp_add2)) {
    echo "<br>$comp_add2"; 
}
```

should be

```
if (!empty($comp_add2)) {
    echo "<br>$comp_add2"; 
}
```

Here is a good explanation regarding isset vs empty:
http://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/